# Windows 7 bat specific network interface for user

Tags: windows, networking, batch-file

I have two network connections and what I need to be able to do is when a specific user logs in to either disable an interface or force use of a specific interface which ever is easiest.

I can disable using

```
netsh interface set interface name="Local Area Connection" admin=disabled
```

however i'm not sure how to setup so it only does it for specific users.

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I run a script when a user logs in

Use a logon script.

> Applies To: Windows 7, Windows Server 2008, Windows Server 2008 R2,
> Windows Server 2012
>
> Administrators is the minimum group membership required to complete
> this procedure. Review the details in "Additional considerations" in
> this topic. To assign a logon script to a local user account
>
> 1. Open Computer Management.
> 2. In the console tree, click Users.
>
>    Where?
>
>    - Computer Management\System Tools\Local Users and Groups\Users
> 3. Right-click the user account that you want, and then click Properties .
> 4. On the Profile tab, in Logon script , type the file name and relative path of the script.

Source [Assign a logon script to a local user account](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771314.aspx)

Comment: I created a batch script in c:\batchscripts then created a shortcut to it in the same folder and selected 'run as administrator' form the properties section. I then added

> Profile Path: C:\batchscripts
>     Logon Script: disablelan-Shortcut.lnk

for the non admin user. When I click on the .Ink file as an admin user I get a pop up box 'following program want sto make changes' etc etc.

Comment: What happens if you don't use a shorcut lnk, but click on the batch file?

Comment: I get "An interface with this name is not registered with the router." this is due to it not being run as admin.

Comment: @Lurch You cannot mark system applications or processes to always run with administrator privileges. Only non-system applications and processes can be marked to always run at this level. See [Configure Applications to Always Run as an Administrator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff431742.aspx) for more information.